# Статичный фон сайта

Tags: html, css

Приветствую.

Есть фон для сайта, и очень важно, чтобы этот фон был статичен и всегда "прилеплен" (при изменении размера окна должен обрезаться фон, а не изменяться его размер) к основному макету. Каким образом это сделать?

Comment: background: url(путь к изобржению) no-repeat fixed center top;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

css:

```
background-attachment:fixed;
background-position:top center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

1. Фиксируем картинку на экране.
2. Прижимаем вверх и по центру.
3. Запрещаем ее повторять.

Comment: А чего бы сразу в одной строчке это не сделать?

Comment: Можно и в одной. Скажем - вредная старая привычка, всегда расписываю отдельно. Да и человеку так понятнее будет, раз он такой вопрос задает, то наверняка не все свойства знает =)